# Locate bitcoin from 11+ years ago

Tags: wallet, address, exchanges, wallet-recovery

I bought bitcoin along time ago. It was at minimum 11 years ago. My bitcoin purchase info was emailed.

I remember the following after buying: getting an email which indicated the bitcoin info. I remember looking at the "garbled" text code I received indicating my bitcoin info. I just don't remember the exact details of the email other than basically don't lose this! (Wow has crypto buying and trading has seen some serious change)

Fast forward, I remember deleting the email and copying the info in a file (not sure which kind either .pdf or word probably) and naming the file under something unassuming. Well, now don't remember the file name and can only hope it is somewhere on my old computer backup before I bought my new computer. I tried searching "account" "bitcoin" "key" "access" but can locate anything.

Assuming I copied the info directly as it was in the email, what can I search for to find what I need? Anyone remember how it was back in the day?? This was so long ago and things have changed so much I really don't remember how it was or what I need to search for.

Comment: Try "seed", "recovery", "passphrase", "BIP39" and the like? https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Seed_phrase

Comment: @C-Otto iirc the keywords you mentioned all came into being at a later time than Zee has mentioned. It may be more helpful to simply search for 'private', 'key', 'paper wallet', 'bitcoin'-- assuming the mentioned timeline is correct.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that you might have used blockchain.info. They would email you your wallet ID after creating a wallet. If you still have access to the email account you used at that time, you can verify whether you will receive an email by inputting your address at the following link:

https://login.blockchain.com/en/#/login?product=wallet